# Add default rows to the query result if restrictions are not met

Tags: sql-server, date-math

I have a SQL query that looks for values in a table on a range of dates.

If no record is found, I would like to generate rows with default values.

Example of one of the table existing records:

| DeviceId | Time | Context | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-02-10 | Connected | False |

So a query that restricts on the Time column between 2022-02-07 and 2022-02-10 must create fake rows for February 7th, 8th, and 9th but not for the 10th because that already exists.

Expected result:

| DeviceId | Time | Context | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-02-7 | Fake | False |
| 1 | 2022-02-8 | Fake | False |
| 1 | 2022-02-9 | Fake | False |
| 1 | 2022-02-10 | Connected | False |

How can I do that? With a recursive CTE?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When I think about what you're trying to accomplish, I would describe it in this way, using "plain English":

- Return the results of some query
- But if no results exist, then return some default values.

My thought process took the immediate leap of "What if I always include the defaults, but then somehow filter them out when there exist real results.

After pondering over my cup of morning coffee, I realized this is actually pretty easy to do with CTEs. No recursion needed, but I will use two CTEs.

### That real query

Lets start by throwing your real query into a CTE. This makes it easy to reference the results from the query multiple times, pretty easily. In this example, I'm just going to query sys.objects, and put the whole darn thing into a CTE:

```sql
DECLARE @ObjectName nvarchar(128) = N'sysschobjs';

RealQuery AS (
    SELECT object_id, name
    FROM sys.objects
    WHERE name = @ObjectName
    )
SELECT *
FROM RealQuery;
```

### Now for the defaults

I'm doing the same treatment here. Just making up some default placeholders, and abstracting them away into a CTE that I can reference easily. Maybe your default values are stored in some table somewhere, or maybe you prefer to stuff them into a `#temp` table or table `@variable`, in which case you wouldn't need to use a CTE here.

```sql
WITH Defaults AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (1,N'One'),(2,N'Two'),(3,N'Three')) AS x(Id,Name)
    )
SELECT *
FROM Defaults;
```

### Time for a mashup

Now, with our real query in a CTE, and our "default" values in another, I simply `UNION ALL` the "real" results and the default place holders. The "magic" is to use `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM RealQuery)` to control whether those defaults are included.

This returns a single row, matching the object name `sysschobjs`, and does not return the default placeholders:

```sql
DECLARE @ObjectName nvarchar(128) = N'sysschobjs';

WITH Defaults AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (1,N'One'),(2,N'Two'),(3,N'Three')) AS x(Id,Name)
    ),
RealQuery AS (
    SELECT object_id, name
    FROM sys.objects
    WHERE name = @ObjectName
    )
SELECT *
FROM RealQuery
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM Defaults
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM RealQuery);
```

[image: SSMS Results of one value for sysschobjs]

And if you change that first line to a value that doesn't exist in `sys.objects` then you'll get the placeholder default results instead:

```sql
DECLARE @ObjectName nvarchar(128) = N'AMtwo';
```

[image: image of three placeholder results, the numbers One, Two, Three spelled out in words]

### There are other ways, too.

My solution works, but it may not be ideal. For example, if you look at [the execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJOnxjMkc), you'll see it's running the "real" query twice. That's totally fine for this trivial query, but for other cases that might not work as well.

You might be better off simply running your "real" query to insert into a `#Results` temp table, then checking how many rows are in the temp table.

```sql
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #Results)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #Results(Id,Name)
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (1,N'One'),(2,N'Two'),(3,N'Three')) AS x(Id,Name);
END;

SELECT *
FROM #Results;
```

Comment: This is great. I actually need a cartesian product to generate default calendar values in a recursive CTE because the deviceid column value is not unique. This will probably be the subject of another question.

Answer (score 8):

It is possible to use pivot and unpivot to achieve this efficiently.

Using slightly expanded test data:

| DeviceId | Time | Context | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-02-08 00:00:00 | Connected | False |
| 1 | 2022-02-10 00:00:00 | Connected | False |
| 2 | 2022-02-09 00:00:00 | Connected | False |

To produce rows from the 7<sup>th</sup> to 11<sup>th</sup> inclusive:

```
WITH TheQuery AS
(
    SELECT V.*
    FROM 
    (
        VALUES
            (1, CONVERT(datetime2(0), '20220208', 112), 'Connected', 'False'),
            (1, CONVERT(datetime2(0), '20220210', 112), 'Connected', 'False'),
            (2, CONVERT(datetime2(0), '20220209', 112), 'Connected', 'False')
    ) AS V (DeviceId, [Time], Context, [Value])
)
SELECT
    U.DeviceId, 
    U.TheDate, 
    Context = IIF(U.Present = 1, U.Context, 'Fake'), 
    [Value] = IIF(U.Present = 1, U.[Value], 'False')
FROM TheQuery AS Q
PIVOT (COUNT([Time]) FOR [Time] IN 
    ([20220207],[20220208],[20220209],[20220210],[20220211])) AS P
UNPIVOT (Present FOR TheDate IN 
    ([20220207],[20220208],[20220209],[20220210],[20220211])) AS U;
```

The pivot part turns the data into:

| DeviceId | Context | Value | 20220207 | 20220208 | 20220209 | 20220210 | 20220211 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Connected | False | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | Connected | False | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

The `COUNT` aggregate results in a zero if the value doesn't exist, or 1 otherwise. The unpivot rotates the set back into rows, with extra ones where the count produced a zero:

| DeviceId | Context | Value | Present | TheDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Connected | False | 0 | 20220207 |
| 1 | Connected | False | 1 | 20220208 |
| 1 | Connected | False | 0 | 20220209 |
| 1 | Connected | False | 1 | 20220210 |
| 1 | Connected | False | 0 | 20220211 |
| 2 | Connected | False | 0 | 20220207 |
| 2 | Connected | False | 0 | 20220208 |
| 2 | Connected | False | 1 | 20220209 |
| 2 | Connected | False | 0 | 20220210 |
| 2 | Connected | False | 0 | 20220211 |

The 'present' column from the count gives an easy way to decide if default values should be used.

The final results are:

| DeviceId | TheDate | Context | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20220207 | Fake | False |
| 1 | 20220208 | Connected | False |
| 1 | 20220209 | Fake | False |
| 1 | 20220210 | Connected | False |
| 1 | 20220211 | Fake | False |
| 2 | 20220207 | Fake | False |
| 2 | 20220208 | Fake | False |
| 2 | 20220209 | Connected | False |
| 2 | 20220210 | Fake | False |
| 2 | 20220211 | Fake | False |

Execution plan:

[image: plan]

The approach lends itself to dynamic SQL because both the pivot and unpivot need a string of quoted comma-separated dates.

This string can be created in many ways, for example:

```
DECLARE 
    @Start datetime2(0) = '20220207',
    @End datetime2(0) = '20220211';

WITH R AS 
(
    SELECT TheDate = @Start
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, R.TheDate)
    FROM R
    WHERE R.TheDate < @End
)
SELECT 
    STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(R.TheDate), ',')
FROM R;
```

Answer (score 7):

Cool answers on this one, but for filling in missing date ranges, my preference is just kicking it classic by using a `DateDimensions` table. [Here's an example](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) of how to generate one by Aaron Bertrand.

Of course if you don't need all the additional fluff of dimensions, you can just generate it for the dates alone. Then all you need is a simple outer join to your `DateDimensions` table by your date field in your other table to *fill the gaps* of the dates you're missing like so:

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(YT.DeviceId, 1) AS DeviceId, 
    DD.[Date] AS [Time], 
    ISNULL(YT.Context, 'Fake') AS Context,
    ISNULL(YT.[Value], 'False') AS [Value]
FROM DateDimensions AS DD
LEFT JOIN YourTable AS YT
    ON DD.[Date] = YT.[Time]
WHERE DD.[Date] >= '2022-02-07'
    AND DD.[Date] <= '2022-02-10'
```

For really large date ranges and datasets this might not be the #1 way for performance, but I find it the simplest and usually is good enough to get you across the finish line, especially when indexed properly.